# How can I put the index number as a value in a foreach?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following code:

```
foreach (var SubTopic in Model.SubTopic.Description)
{
 <option value="xxx">SubTopic</option>
}
```

I would like to find a way to insert the index number into xxx as value. 01 for the first, 02 for the second option line etc.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Sorry, this is not C#... what are you developing? A website with ASP.NET?

Comment: Well, why don't u jus use a regular for loop.

Comment: just looking for the best way. Yeah I could use a regular for but also wondering if there is a way to access the index value of the loop with a foreach

Comment: I see you're new here, so I give you a suggestion: be careful to choose your tags correctly so people can help you better. :)

Answer (score 9):

Use a for loop like

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.SubTopic.Description.Count; i++)
    <option value="i">Model.SubTopic.Description[i]</option>
```

In C# you cannot directly access the actual index from within a foreach loop.

Answer (score 2):

declare a variable with initial value 0 outside the loop and increment it inside the loop.

Comment: Actually, declare it outside of the loop and increment it inside.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume that the collection has no facility for retrieving items by index (like `List`) otherwise you would have used a simple `for` loop.

The `foreach` construct has no builtin mechanisms for doing this, but it is easy enough to accomplish with a helper class.

```
foreach (var item in ForEachHelper.WithIndex(Model.SubTopic.Description))
{
  Console.WriteLine("<option value=\"" + item.Index.ToString("00") + "\">" + item.Value + "</option");
}
```

And here is what the helper class looks like.

```
public static class ForEachHelper
{
    public sealed class Item<T>
    {
        public int Index { get; set; }
        public T Value { get; set; }
        public bool IsLast { get; set; }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Item<T>> WithIndex<T>(IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
    {
        Item<T> item = null;
        foreach (T value in enumerable)
        {
            Item<T> next = new Item<T>();
            next.Index = 0;
            next.Value = value;
            next.IsLast = false;
            if (item != null)
            {
                next.Index = item.Index + 1;
                yield return item;
            }
            item = next;
        }
        if (item != null)
        {
            item.IsLast = true;
            yield return item;
        }            
    }
}
```